# Systems of equations calculator getting "NaN"

Tags: java, math, nan

Here is my code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
  public class SysQ {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);


System.out.print("Enter A: ");
double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter B: ");
double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter C: ");
double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter X: ");
double x = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter Y: ");
double y = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter Z: ");
double z = keyboard.nextDouble();


   double fixedequation2 = x * b;
   double fixedequation3 = x * c;
   double fixedequation5 = a * y;
   double fixedequation6 = a * z;



double final1 = fixedequation2 - fixedequation5;
double final2 = fixedequation3 - fixedequation6;
double yanswer = final2/final1;



double x1 = c - (b * yanswer);
double xanswer = x1/a;

System.out.println("X is " + xanswer);
System.out.println("Y is " + yanswer);
```

So the code works for most numbers for a 2 x 2 equation, but when I put in the values 5,5,5,5,5,5 for a,b,c,x,y,z, I get "NaN" I just want to know does "NaN" mean infinitely many solutions or No Solution..

Answer (score 2):

**NaN** means "not a number". You get that solution because you are doing

`(25-25)/(25-25) = 0/0`, the result of which is undefined, or "Not a number"

Comment: Oh I see, but does that go under No solution or infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @WinterOne I guess you would say "no solutions". Someone more advanced at math might correct me on that as it might not be technically correct.

Comment: @WinterOne This type fo forms are undefined 0/0